# Fit the items without space between the rows using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to create this image effect using flex?

[image]

The divs have different sizes due to their content, and when they reach the container's width limit, they move to the next row but stay below the item above.

When the screen is small, like a smartphone, they would be in a single column.

Comment: Can you please share the things that you tried? Using that maybe it'll be easy to answer.